# How to add image tags to a string

Tags: php, regex

I am a bit stuck using regex, in a line of text there is an image path, such as:

```
hello images/image.jpg this is an image
```

What I am trying to do is to add the HTML img tag to the path, so that it looks like

```
hello <img src="images/image.jpg" /> this is an image
```

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will match any chunk of text that ends with `.jpg` and wrap it in an `<img>` tag:

```
preg_replace('/\b\S+\.jpg\b/', '<img src="$0" />', $str);
```